# How to use a vector list to find all instances of words in a file

Tags: c++

So I'm stuck at a point in my code. I need to make a function that can be used to find instances of a list of words in a file.

So, for example, I currently have it to where I can type Breaking-Bad, or Lilo-Stitch; these words are then broken to [breaking, bad] [lilo, stitch] in a vector. The issues arise when I use the function on the bottom.

The function works when it comes to the first index; it will find all instances of the words, like [breaking] or [lilo], but it doesn't output anything else for the other indexes. How can I improve on this section of code?

To further explain, the idea of the code is to find all lines in the file that have one to all of the words typed by the user.

```
int searchfile(fstream& file, vector<string>& UserSearch, int counter)
{
    string input;
    int amount = 0;
    int line = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        while (getline(file, input))
        {
            line++;

            if (input.find(UserSearch[i], 0) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << "found " << UserSearch[i] << " in line " << line << endl;
                amount++;
            }

        }
    }
    return amount;
}
```

I already tried using a for loop in main but it gave the same results.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size; i++) {
searchFile(infile, list, counter);
}
```

Comment: Not too clear what you want to find in the results...Can you be more clear?

Comment: OK to clarify, so say I typed Breaking-Bad. This function would output all the line numbers in the word file that have the word Breaking, and also output line numbers that have the word bad.

Comment: the code currently outputs all the number lines for breaking, and stops at that. It doesn't go on and displays the lines that have the word bad.

Comment: On the first iteration of the loop, you read the file through to the end. On the second iteration, `getline` fails immediately since it has already reached end of file. Turn your loops around - read lines in the outer loop, and then search for each term in that line, in the inner loop. So that you can find all matches in a single pass over the file.

Comment: Hint: a way to approach this is simply create a hashtable, hash the line read from the file and store the line in the associated bucket. That way a search simply become hashing the line and checking if that hash currently exits in your table. No need to split words or store a vector<string> for each line in your file. Your hash node can contain the line as a string, a counter and your next-pointer for chaining in the event of a hash collision.